# Creating and overlaying on a image in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I would like to know how to create an image in code.

For example A blue field X by X pixels with a red line and some text. I have a goal of adding a splash to an actual image similar to how the sports channels have a stripe and some words. Right now I am focusing on the basics of adding elements to a new blank image.

[image]

This type of image with transparencies overlay is a related goal. 
[image]

The very basics of this can be done trivially in regular .net like this:

```
...
Bitmap flag = new Bitmap(200, 100);
Graphics flagGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag);
int red = 0;
int white = 11;
while (white <= 100) {
    flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, red, 200,10);
    flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, white, 200, 10);
    red += 20;
    white += 20;
}
...
```

System.Drawing is obviously castrated in .netstandard20 :(

I have spent a lot of time on other things that have had a simple answer if I had asked first. Hoping this is like that.

My thanks in advance

Comment: check out SkiaSharp

Comment: I would second Jason's comment. SkiaSharp enables you to do custom drawing quite quickly and also allows you to do the drawing code in your shared codebase.

Check the overview on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/graphics-games/skiasharp/index)

Comment: Checking out SkiaSharp now.